# XUnit project can't reference project referenced by the project it's testing

Tags: visual-studio, xunit, project-reference

I'm creating a project I've named `Amino` which builds on the `Monogame`/`XNA` C# game framework.

I've also created an XUnit test for Amino, called `Amino.UnitTest`.

In the unit test, I'm able to interact with classes from Amino, but not classes from XNA. This is a problem because I need to deal with `Vector2`s and other things that XNA defines.

```
// "The type or namespace Xna does not exist"
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Xunit;

namespace Amino.UnitTest
{
    public class MatrixTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SimpleTest()
        {
            Matrix3x3 m = new Matrix3x3();
            // "Vector2 is defined in an assembly that is not referenced."
            Vector2 v = m.Up;
        }
    }
}
```

My project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Amino\Amino.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The structure of the solution is:

```
Solution.sln
-- Amino.csproj
-- Amino.UnitTest.csproj
-- GameThatUsesAmino.csproj
```